# Comparing 2 strings and find out mismatches

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to create a query in MariaDB 10.2. I am trying to create a query with string functions as now

Below is the scenario

One string has placeholders and another string has values of those placeholders. I want to get a tabular output in which one column have placeholders and another column have placeholder's values

**value1**  -->
jdbc:postgresql://**$PGHOST_1$**:**$PGPORT_INSTANCE_1$**/eventstore

**value2**  -->
jdbc:postgresql://**1.2.3.4**:**5432**/eventstore

now i want to get below data

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have forgotten to include what you have tried that isn't working. Please [edit] you question to include the code you have tried.

Comment: I am trying to create a query with string functions as now, I will proceed with the loop if that doesn't work.

Comment: Which two strings?  Are they in separate columns in the same table?  Is one in a table, and the other is a literal?  Two rows in a table?  Do you need case folding?  What about accent stripping?

Comment: @RickJames: They can be separate columns in the same table or columns from different tables or one column and one literal. I think none of this will impact the basic query.

Comment: Comparing two strings with `=` gives you "true" or "false".  What do you mean by the plural "mismatches"?

Comment: @RickJames: I don't want output in true or false.  You can see my required output in the description.

Comment: I don't understand the sample output.  Give us another example.

Comment: @RickJames One string has placeholders and another string has values of those placeholders. I want to get a tabular output in which one column have placeholders and another column have placeholder's values

Answer (score 0):

This needs a looping mechanism.  Therefore, use a stored procedure or client code to do the looping:

```
SELECT placeholder, `value` FROM mylist;
`col` starts out looking like `value1`
foreach row in the list of replacements:
    UPDATE mytable SET col =
        REPLACE(col, placeholder, `value`);
Now `col` looks like your `value2`
```

or, if you don't want to change `col`:

```
SELECT placeholder, `value` FROM mylist;
SELECT @col := col FROM mytable;
foreach row in the list of replacements:
    SET @col =
        REPLACE(@col, placeholder, `value`);
then use @col in subsequent work
```

(`value` is a keyword, hence the backtics.)

From there, build the "mismatches".